# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: media, .htaccess

I've been embedding an image with my page using item type form control in Drupal 7 Forms API.Below are my codes:

```
function myid_user_page_form(){  
    $form = array(); 
    $form['id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('ID Information'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );

    $form['id']['myid'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => 
            '<div id="divID"><img src="images/id-background.jpg" alt="ID Picture"/></div>'
    );
    return $form;
}
```

My image doesnt show up and is broken eventhough the path is correct and file permissions are set properly.

What Shall I Do? Below is the error:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/drupal-7.34/user/7/images/id-background.jpg".
```

Below is a screen capture of my page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image path is incorrect. It will pick the path of image as `http://current_path/images/id-background.jpg`.

```
global $base_url;
$path = $base_url . drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/images/id-background.jpg'; // considering the image is placed in your custom module's image directory
$form['id']['myid'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => '<div id="divID"><img src="' . $path . '" alt="ID Picture"/></div>'
);
```